# Using $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-x^2/2}\text{ d}x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^3e^{-x^2/\beta^2}\text{ d}x$, $\beta > 0$

Tags: integration

Given $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-x^2/2}\text{ d}x = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$$ how can I calculate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^3e^{-x^2/\beta^2}\text{ d}x\text{, }\beta > 0\text{?}$$

I am more interested in the **thought process** behind this problem - which isn't necessarily the solution.

My first thought was to attempt the substitution $\dfrac{u^2}{2} = \dfrac{x^2}{\beta^2}$ - but notice this makes 
$$x = \sqrt{\dfrac{\beta^2}{2}u^2} = \dfrac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}u \implies x^3 = \dfrac{\beta^3}{2^{3/2}}u^3$$
so that $\text{d}x = \dfrac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\text{ d}u$,
giving me 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^3e^{-x^2/\beta^2}\text{ d}x = \dfrac{\beta^3}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^3e^{-u^2/2}\text{ d}u$$
and this isn't *quite* what I need.

Please do not make any other assumptions and don't use any special formulas other than what I've stated above.

Comment: Try integration by parts to reduce the power of $x$.

Comment: @JonWarneke Do you mean $u$ or do you mean $x$?

Comment: Whichever. You're dealing with the same integral in either case up to a constant factor.

Comment: @JonWarneke Never mind, my comment is wrong.

Comment: Substitute $u=x^2$, and it becomes straightforward integration by parts.

Comment: It is not clear how the value of the $x^2$ integral can be useful to compute the $x^3$ integral. Is this a mistake? (It helps for the $x^{2n}$ integrals, not for the $x^{2n+1}$ integrals.)

Comment: @Did Dang it, you're right. I thought it might've used that, but it turns out I'm wrong.

Comment: Where does the idea to use the $x^2$ case come from?

Comment: @Did This was a two-part problem, where the first part involved the same integral except with $x^2$ in place of $x^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly that you want  because it doesn't really use the given identity, but integrating by parts using $u = x^2, dv = xe^{-x^2/\beta^2} dx$, we find \begin{align*}\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-x^2/\beta^2} dx &= \underbrace{\left[-\frac{\beta^2 x^2}{2}e^{-x^2/\beta^2}\right]^{x\to\infty}_{x=0}}_{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ = 0}  + \beta^2\int^\infty_0x e^{-x^2/\beta^2}dx\\
&= \left[-\frac{\beta^4}{2} e^{-x^2/\beta^2} \right]_{x=0}^{x\to\infty} = \frac{\beta^4} 2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Other than just trial-and-error and practice, what made you think to choose what you did for $u$ and $\text{d}v$?

Comment: Just edited because my first solution was incorrect. I chose that $dv$ because it has an elementary anti-derivative which makes integration by parts much easier. The $u$ was then just chosen to be whatever was left over.

Comment: Two things. First, you're trying to reduce the power of $x$ in the integral to use your given $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ formula. the $u$ term gets differentiated, which reduces powers of polynomials. Secondly, your $dv$ term must be anti-differentiable; since it contains $e^{-x^2/\beta^2}$, this limits your options.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$I(\alpha)= \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\alpha x^2/2}\text{ d}x$$
we have
$$I'(\alpha)=-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}x^3e^{-\alpha x^2/2}\text{ d}x$$
Note
$$I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\alpha x^2/2}\text{ d}x=\frac{1}{\alpha}$$

Comment: This is a great solution, but it requires that I justify differentiating under the integral sign... which, quite frankly, I'm not interested in doing (and this has not been covered yet at this point in the textbook).

Comment: It's  just an alternative solution.

Comment: I like this solution better than the one I posted below. This method of inserting a parameter and fiddling around with derivatives proves to be a very powerful tool for evaluating a huge amount of tricky integrals.

Comment: @User8128 Thanks.

Comment: This isn't correct.  Differentiating produces $x^4$, not $x^3$.

Comment: Sorry, It was typo. I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^3 e^{-x^2}\,dx $ is an elementary integral that can be computed by integration by parts:
$$ \int x^3 e^{-x^2}\,dx =-\frac{1+x^2}{2}e^{-x^2} $$
while $\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-x^2}\,dx $ is not, but anyway
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^k e^{-x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} z^{\frac{k-1}{2}}e^{-z}\,dz = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right). $$
In general, there is no way to compute $\Gamma\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ from $\Gamma(x)$ only with a simple formula, hence I guess there is some typo in your exercise, or maybe the intended one was to compute 
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{\color{red}{4}} e^{-x^2/\beta^2}\,dx $$
from $\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-x^2}\,dx$. That makes sense since $\Gamma(x+1)=x\cdot\Gamma(x)$. The $\beta$ parameter is just syntactic sugar since it can be removed through the substitution $x=\beta z$.

Comment: (+1). Indeed $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^m e^{-ax^n}dx=\frac{1}{na^{\frac{m+1}{n}}}\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{n}\right)$$